# Direct links to the new SEDE graphs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

I [noticed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/stack-exchange-data-explorer-2-0/) we can now generate graphs on SEDE (Awesome!!), but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any way to provide a link directly to the graph tab of a query.

Is there any chance we can get support for links of the following form where the last `/graph` causes the graph tab to be selected by default?

```
http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36359/answers-by-time-of-week/graph
```

Generally when providing a link to a query like this, the graph is more interesting than the wall of numbers. And telling the recipient to "Click the graph tab" feels "clunky".

Comment: SEDE Graphs aren't even a day old, and there's already a feature request! Let the developers think their latest masterpiece is beyond improving, at least for a couple of days...

Comment: While I agree with the idea, I think letting the tabs change the hash works best (renaming `#resultSets` to `#results` and such).  Then you'd just link to `#graph` on the end, with no effort.  Just clicking the tab and copying your address bar (or right click/copy url on the tab) both work.

Comment: @Nick, I'm more than happy to go with the '#' idea, I just figured (assumed) there might be some complications with getting it to work since it seems to be ignored when merely adding it to the url.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll look into this this evening if it's not [meta-tag:status-completed] by then.

Comment: @TimStone I am fine with you to take it ... but I don't want html5 history there ... just append a #graph etc as you click on the tabs

Comment: @waffles Yeah, I was thinking a simple hash-based solution too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per my comment, this is something that I've been meaning to implement for some time. I don't really have a good explanation for why it ended up taking so long, but I've finally gone ahead added this now.

Clicking result tabs will now add the relevant hash to the URL and the permalink (if you're on the editor page) when it's useful (i.e. you're not on the default tab), and running the query with that URL will cause it to autoselect the appropriate tab when displaying the results.

This also has the additional side-effect of maintaining the currently selected tab when you're creating new revisions in the query editor. At the moment that seems like a good thing, but in the event that it isn't we can go back and tweak it in the future.

Should go out in the next build > 2012.8.31.5, or shortly thereafter. Sorry about the wait.